# How can I navigate my Facebook iframe with a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-iframe

Usually one would use:

```
document.location = 'http://www.mozilla.org';
```

or

```
window.frames[0].location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
```

But the window and document objects dont seem to be accessible from my facebook iframe app. I even tried having an empty link getting that and calling click() on it but the <a> element doesnt support that method..

Comment: Are you sure you can't do `document.location` from within the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
top.location.href = 'http://www.mozilla.org';
```

To change the iframe only:

```
location.href = 'http://www.mozilla.org';
```

Result:
[image: Mozilla Page inside Facebook iframe]

Comment: Though using top I can do it: top.frames[0].location.href = "http://www.mozilla.org", if you put that in your answer I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Fëanor: Why you are doing this? updated my answer with how you do it

Comment: Thanks. Because I want my app to do it with a button rather than a link - I am not navigating to another site it is just a page within my site.

Comment: @Fëanor: Did my update help? it should work for input type button